# Accumulate subprojects' `discoveredMainClasses`

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

How can I accumulate all the `discoveredMainClasses` of a project, along with its dependent sub projects in SBT?

For example, I have a project that looks like

```
├── bar
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── scala
│               └── BarMain.scala
├── build.sbt
├── foo
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── scala
│               └── FooMain.scala
├── project
│   └── build.properties
└── root
```

With one `root` project that `aggregate(foo, bar)`, I get the following for `discoveredMainClasses`:

```
[info] foo/compile:discoveredMainClasses
[info]  List(MainFoo)
[info] bar/compile:discoveredMainClasses
[info]  List(MainBar)
[info] root/compile:discoveredMainClasses
[info]  List()
```

With one `root` that only `dependsOn(foo, bar)` I get

```
> show discoveredMainClasses
[info] *
```

How can I have `show root/discoveredMainClasses` contain both `MainFoo` and `MainBar`?

For context, I have other tasks that depend on the output from `discoveredMainClasses` namely the `makeBashScripts` in [native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/12d03df55aeea8dd7b2ff532bdc2b4984f0ed521/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/archetypes/scripts/BashStartScriptPlugin.scala#L68-L79)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core idea is to create a module that depends on all all the sub modules you want to include and configure all settings on this module.

This results in a `build.sbt` like this

```
lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
  // package the root module, but not the sub modules
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
  .settings(
    name := "application",
    // add the discoveredMainClasses to this project
    discoveredMainClasses in Compile ++= (discoveredMainClasses in (client, Compile)).value,
    discoveredMainClasses in Compile ++= (discoveredMainClasses in (server, Compile)).value
  )
  // include these modules in the resulting package
  .dependsOn(client, server)

lazy val client = project.in(file("client"))
  .settings(
    name := "client"
  )

lazy val server = project.in(file("server"))
  .settings(
    name := "server"
  )
```

The `(discoveredMainClasses in (client, Compile)).value` accesses the discoveredMainClasses from the client project in the Compile scope.

You can build and run your applications with

```
$ sbt universal:stage
$ ./target/universal/stage/bin/client-app
$ ./target/universal/stage/bin/server-app
```

A [running example can be found here](https://github.com/muuki88/sbt-native-packager-examples/tree/master/accumulated-main-classes).

cheers,
Muki

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to @Muki's answer would be to define a ScopeFilter that includes everything but `root` and accumulate main classes that way. This has the advantage of not having to repeat `client`, `server` everywhere.

The resulting `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val allCompileButRootFilter = 
  ScopeFilter(inAggregates(ThisProject, includeRoot = false), inConfigurations(Compile))

lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
  .aggregate(client, server)
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
  .settings(
    discoveredMainClasses in Compile ++= 
      discoveredMainClasses.all(allCompileButRootFilter).value.flatten,
    ...
  )
```